# Trigger to count of related contacts on Account based on checkbox field

Tags: apex, trigger

Can someone please help me get this sorted

Scenario:
There are 2 checkbox fields, Team_X__c and Team_Y__c, on Contact object and there are 2 fields, Total_X_Contacts__c & Total_Y_Contacts__c, on Account.

Whenever the user created the record with checkbox Team_X__c as true it should add the count to the Total_X_Contacts__c field and whenever user creates record with Team_Y__c as true it should add the count to the Total_Y_Contacts__c.

I have written the below code, but it is updating on both the fields Total_X_Contacts__c & Total_Y_Contacts__c

Trigger:

```java
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after delete, after insert, after update, after undelete) {
    List<Contact> lstcon2 = Trigger.new;
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        ContactDispatcher.updateAccountIds(lstcon2);
    }
}
```

Handler Class:

```java
public class ContactDispatcher {
    public static void updateAccountIds(List<Contact> lstcon2){
        Set<Id> setIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Contact con : lstcon2){
            setIds.add(con.AccountId);
        }
        List<Account> lstAcc = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> lstAcc2 = new List<Account>();
        
        for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Total_X_Contacts__c, Total_Y_Contacts__c, (SELECT Id, Team_X__c, Team_Y__c FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :setIds]){
            
            for(contact con : acc.Contacts){
                if(con.Team_X__c == true){
                    acc.Total_X_Contacts__c = acc.contacts.size();
                }
                else if(con.Team_Y__c == true){
                    acc.Total_Y_Contacts__c = acc.contacts.size();
                }
            }
            lstAcc.add(acc);
        }
        if(!lstAcc.isEmpty()){
            update lstAcc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Do you know about Aggregate queries? This is a perfect candidate for that. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you're running into here in your handler is that `acc.contacts.size()` doesn't distinguish between your two Contact fields, it's simply the count of all of the Contacts related to the current Account. You're also overwriting the count fields on your Account multiple times, but since the number of Contacts under each Account isn't changing, this issue isn't causing you problems.

Directly accessing/operating on the result of a subquery is also generally unsafe. Your current code does take the safe approach (using a nested for loop to access the related Contact records), but I think this worth mentioning for others who find this question in the future. If/when you have ~200 child records related to a single parent, you'd start running into an error like "Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop". If you know *for certain* that you will not have >= 200 child records (like if you have a `LIMIT 10` in the subquery), then it is safe to directly access. In general though, I recommend just going with a nested loop (for safety).

The first approach that JNR describes (the second approach being very similar) is the simplest change that you could make. Put simply, it:

- Iterates over Accounts, and initialize the count fields to 0
- Iterates over the Contacts for each given account, and increment the appropriate field

Personally, I like to avoid using loops to do simple counting/addition. As mentioned in the comments, SOQL is capable of doing this for you by using [Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) and `GROUP BY`.

Normally, you would only group by a single field, but your scenario requires that you group by multiple fields. What you're looking to do is possible with a single query. You just need to know what result to expect from it to be able to effectively work with it.

The query should be

```
[SELECT COUNT(Id), AccountId, Team_X__c, Team_Y__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds GROUP BY AccountId, Team_X__c, Team_Y__c ]
```

If your two checkboxes are mutually exclusive (enforced by a validation rule, for example), and one is always required to be checked, then you could simplify this by only grouping by AccountId and one of the two checkbox fields.

The result you'll get from that query would look like

| Count | Account Id | Team X | Team Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 001000000000001 | true | false |
| 2 | 001000000000001 | false | true |
| 5 | 001000000000002 | true | false |
| 7 | 001000000000002 | false | true |
| 17 | 001000000000003 | false | true |

The key things to notice here are:

- The order of your `GROUP BY` matters, the leftmost field is grouped first, and it proceeds left-to-right
- There can be multiple rows for each grouped field, and in that case there will be at least one difference in the grouped field value compared to the row before
- You need to include your grouped fields in the `SELECT` clause so you can tell rows apart
- If there are no records for a particular combination of grouped fields (like Team X = true and Team Y = false for the "003" mock Account Id) then it will not be included in the results

With that knowledge, we can re-build your handler.

```java
public static void updateAccountIds(List<Contact> lstcon2){
    // Aggregating account Ids is the right thing to do, so this remains unchanged
    Set<Id> setIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact con : lstcon2){
        setIds.add(con.AccountId);
    }

    // Since we can encounter the same Account Id multiple times, using a Map
    //   will make it easy to build the Account incrementally
    Map<Id, Account> accountsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();

    // This work could be done inside of the SOQL for-loop below, but doing it in a separate
    //   loop like this ensures that our map will have default values even if there
    //   are no more child records for a given parent.
    // This is essential for properly handling deletions.
    for(Id acctId :setIds){
        // Checking if the key exists in the map, and putting something into the map
        //   if it doesn't, is my preferred approach to building Maps.
        // Saves just a bit of typing (as it allows us to omit the else block)
        //   if you're going to use the map further in the same loop that you're
        //   building it in
        if(!accountsToUpdate.containsKey(acctId)){
            // Two key points here:
            // 1) We're setting the account Id via the SObject constructor.
            //    This allows us to update a record without explicitly querying for it first
            // 2) We're setting default values.
            //    This is because if there aren't any contacts for, say, Team Y, the
            //    query we're about to perform won't include that row.
            //    Without this, your count would get stuck at the last non-zero value
            accountsToUpdate.put(acctId, new Account(Id = acctId, Total_X_Contacts__c = 0, Total_Y_Contacts__c = 0));
        }
    }

    // Using GROUP BY and/or aggregate functions means that we'll get an "AggregateResult"
    //   back
    // We'll need to use .get() and typecasting to work with that
    for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT COUNT(Id), AccountId, Team_X__c, Team_Y__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :setIds GROUP BY AccountId, Team_X__c, Team_Y__c]){
        Id acctId = (Id)ar.get('AccountId');
       
        // Maps generally hold non-primitive types as references
        // So we can fetch the account once (to save typing) and any changes we make to
        //   it will be reflected in the map
        Account targetAcct = accountsToUpdateMap.get(acctId);

        // Booleans do not need to be equality tested with true/false, they can be used
        //   directly
        if((Boolean)ar.get('Team_X__c') && !(Boolean)ar.get('Team_Y__c')){
            targetAcct.Total_X_Contacts__c = (Integer)ar.get('expr0');
        }else if(!(Boolean)ar.get('Team_X__c') && (Boolean)ar.get('Team_Y__c')){
            targetAcct.Total_Y_Contacts__c = (Integer)ar.get('expr0');
        }
    }

    update accountsToUpdate.values();
}
```

That's 19 lines of code by my count (less the comments).

It doesn't properly handle records being transferred between parents, but that'd be a simple enough fix (just pass in and iterate over trigger.old as well so that you get the complete list of Account Ids that need to be processed).

It also is able to distinguish between Contacts with one checkbox checked, and those with either both or neither checked (in which case they are ignored an will not contribute towards either count).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this way, you must change code as below:

```
for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Total_X_Contacts__c, Total_Y_Contacts__c, (SELECT Id, Team_X__c, Team_Y__c FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :setIds]){
    Integer teamYcounter = 0;
    Integer teamXcounter = 0;

    for(contact con : acc.Contacts){
        if(con.Team_X__c == true){
            teamXcounter++;
        }
        else if(con.Team_Y__c == true){
            teamYcounter++;
        }
    }

     acc.Total_X_Contacts__c = teamXcounter;
     acc.Total_Y_Contacts__c = teamYcounter;

    lstAcc.add(acc);
}
```

But I wont recomend "nested for" unless there are no other way.
You can use Maps for this to improve code performance.

You can archieve the same result by using maps this way:

```
Map<String, List<Contact>> accountIdContactsMap = new Map<String, List<Contact>>();

for(Contact con : lstcon2){
    if(accountIdContactsMap.containsKey(con.AccountId)){
        accountIdContactsMap.get(con.AccountId).add(con);
    } else {
        accountIdContactsMap.put(con.AccountId, new List<Contact>{con});
    }
}

if(!accountIdContactsMap.isEmpty()){
    Map<Id, Account> accountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Total_X_Contacts__c, Total_Y_Contacts__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIdContactsMap.keySet()]);

    for(Contact con : accountIdContactsMap.values()){
        Account acc = accountsMap.get(con.AccountId);

        if(con.Team_X__c == true){
            acc.Total_X_Contacts__c = acc.Total_X_Contacts__c + 1;
        } else if (con.Team_Y__c == true){
            acc.Total_Y_Contacts__c = acc.Total_Y_Contacts__c + 1;
        }
    }

    update accountsMap.values();
}
```

As you can see, we can avoid nested fors, as total iterations will be n * m (where n is nº of parent 'for' iterations, and m is nº of child 'for' iterations).

Using maps you may prevent hitting governor limits if this process takes lots of records.

*** By the way, you dont need to do this:

```
if(!lstAcc.isEmpty()){
    update lstAcc;
}
```

As Salesforce internally is doing it for you. You can check this by executing this on anonymous console:

```
List<Account> lstAcc = new List<Account>();
update lstAcc;
```

And then check DMLs performed on that transaction (which will be 0)

Comment: The nested for loop approach isn't `O(n*m)`, but rather `O(n+m)`, which is much more manageable. The reason it's addition instead of multiplication is because you're not iterating over every Account's Contacts for every Account, only the Contacts for that particular Account. You should also keep in mind that parent-child subqueries cannot execute the internal call to `queryMore()`, so a nested for loop is _required_ when there's the possibility of more than ~200 child records for a given parent (and is something I generally recommend for safety).

Comment: @DerekF You are asumming this is not working in Bulk, otherwise if you have 10 accounts (n) and every account has 10 Contacts (m), nested for will be 10*10 which means 100 iterations, ofcourse if its not bulkified will be 1+10

Comment: Your choices of n and m in your example are incorrect. 10 accounts with 10 contacts each would have n = 10 and m = 100. The `for(accounts){ for(account.contacts){}}` approach loops a total of n+m = 110 times. The n*m pattern that we're trying to avoid here would look like `for(allAccounts){ for(allContacts){ if(contact.AccountId == account.Id){} } }`. The important distinction is that the inner loop of the former only iterates over Contacts _related to the current Account in the outer loop_. Nested loops are not inherently evil.

Comment: @DerekF I think i missunderstood you and I did not post exactly what I meant.
By this statement O(n+m) I think you mean n + (n*m) which is correct.

Here is what i want to mean: approach loops a total of n+m (where m is outter loops * inner loops) = 110 times